# Как записать ответ метода в .json файл - NodeJS

Tags: node.js

Есть такой кусок кода:

```
var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');

gplay.search({term: "vpn", num: 20}).then(console.log);
```

Он выводит мне в консоль ответ:

> [
>     {
>       title: 'Secure VPN – A high speed, ultra secure VPN',
>       appId: 'com.fast.free.unblock.secure.vpn',
>       url: 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fast.free.unblock.secure.vpn',
>       icon: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Zc-JF30sqOGzgcYXHvAn3DfjaD9vc9UXnHZvdy4AifTQaISCKKqEsuGXFo2s0pWnIA',
>       developer: 'Signal Lab',
>       developerId: '6481577571535301345',
>       priceText: 'FREE',
>       free: true,
>       summary: 'Secure VPN – A high speed, ultra secure, lightning fast VPN',
>       scoreText: '4.6',
>       score: 4.621746
>     },
>     {
>       title: 'Turbo VPN- Free VPN Proxy Server & Secure Service',
>       appId: 'free.vpn.unblock.proxy.turbovpn',
>       url: 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=free.vpn.unblock.proxy.turbovpn',
>       icon: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/G7AkY7FY1XZQU8Xp_h5OGGovDxySJ2tLSlPxNRfl9E3lKDzyqY-2QYByz3CHovWRcg',
>       developer: 'Innovative Connecting',
>       developerId: 'Innovative+Connecting',
>       priceText: 'FREE',
>       free: true,
>       summary: 'Best unlimited free VPN to unblock sites, WiFi hotspot security, protect privacy',
>       scoreText: '4.6',
>       score: 4.620028
>     }
>   ]

Как эти данные записать в .json файл?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Answer (score 0):

Данное выражение `gplay.search(...)` в качестве результата возвращает объект `Promise` (если еще не знакомы с этим термином, читайте [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) и [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1166265/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-promise-javascript/1169252#1169252)).

В конструкции `then` в качестве аргумента вы можете передать ссылку на функцию или саму `callback-функцию`, в которой должна быть реализация обработки полученных данных.

Если полученные данные пришли в виде объекта, тогда их необходимо конвертировать в строку, потому как объекты сохранять в файлы нельзя.

```js
// конвертируем объект в json-текст
// и задаем пробельный отступ размером в 4 шага
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
```

Сохранить файл в Node.js можно тремя разными способами: с помощью callback-метода, синхронно, асинхронно. Давайте рассмотрим каждый способ подробно:

**Callback-метод**

```js
var fs = require('fs');

function writeFileCallback(error) {
  if (error) {
    // произошла ошибка, выводим её на экран и завершаем функцию
    return console.error(error);
  }
  // ошибки нет
  console.log('Файл сохранен!');
}

// задаем кодировку
var options = { encoding: 'utf8' };

// Сохраняем файл указав ссылку на callback-метод:
fs.writeFile('dump.json', jsonData, options, writeFileCallback);
```

**Анонимный callback-метод**

```js
var fs = require('fs');

// Сохраняем файл задав ананимный callback-метод:
fs.writeFile('dump.json', jsonData, 'utf8', function(error) {
  if (error) {
    return console.error(error);
  }
  console.log('Файл сохранен!');
});
```

**Синхронно**

```js
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFileSync('dump.json', jsonData, 'utf8');
```

**Асинхронно**

```js
var fs = require('fs');

gplay.search(...)
.then(function(data) {
  return fs.promises.writeFile('dump.json', jsonData, 'utf8');
})
.then(function () {
  console.log('Файл сохранен!');
})
.catch(function(error) => {
  // Произошла какая-то ошибка
  console.error(error);
});
```

Подробности смотрите в официальной [документации](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]