# Проблема с пониманием Promise (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Уже сижу целую неделю и никак не могу понять Promise. Все что знаю, это то, что это связанно с асинхронностью в JS (скорее ее имитацией). Мне еще дали задание по ним на курсах от одной компании, предварительно не разобрав тему...

```js
//Представьте ситуацию: у вас есть необходимость составить объект с данными о пользователе,
// который в дальнейшем будете использовать в работе.
const promise1 = new Promise(resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => Promise.resolve('Cherkasy'), 1000); // локация
} 
const promise2 = new Promise(resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => Promise.resolve('admin'), 4000); // ролей три - guest, user, admin
} 

const promise3 = new Promise(resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => Promise.resolve('1'), 2000); // id пользователя, можете юзать любое число
}
const promise4 = new Promise(resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => Promise.resolve(['Саша', 'Влад', 'Юля', 'Андрей', 'Богдан']), 1000); // массив который показывает людей, состоящих в группе у человека
}
//Необходимо построить цепочку промисов.
```

- Первый промис - отдает локацию пользователя (город).
- Второй - его роль и в зависимости от роли вам необходимо составить ему email(если пользователь admin - email должен заканчиваться на admin.com и аналогично с другими ролями).
- Далее если пользователь admin вам необходимо вызвать функцию, передав в нее id пользователя и в зависимости от id вернуть число, которое будет обозначать к-во человек в его группе (для этой функции можно юзать промисификацию, соответствие id к к-ву человек придумайте сами, это может быть объект с ключом id и значением к-вом человек. {1: 3, 2: 5} и тд)
- Итого если пользователь на админ, а пришел цепочка должна проигнорировать список человек в группе, только выкинуть ошибку с помощью throw new Error(текст ошибки туть). Если пользователь админ но пришло к-во человек в группе больше, чем указано - выкинуть соответствующую ошибку, цепочка проминов должна завершиться с ошибкой которая дает понять что случилось.
- Для построения подобных сценариев вы можете изменять исходное состояние промисов, делая их rejected если необходимо. Так же данные что передаются тоже можно изменять, но не изменяем время в setTimeout.

Собственно вот задание. Я не понимаю как строить цепочку промисов, что должно за чем идти, где должны быть какие-то вложенности. Прошу кто может объяснить? Или может мне нужно предварительно что-то знать, чтоб понять это?

Comment: примеры промисов `const promise1 = new Promise(resolve) => { setTimeout(() => Promise.resolve('Cherkasy'), 1000); } ` ты сам придумывал или это именно так и в задаче было?

Comment: Лишняя скобка после resolve

Comment: @Vasily, она не лишняя, она просто не в том месте стоит

Comment: В js нет имитации асинхронности, там просто асинхронность

Comment: А как именно вы целую неделю пытаетесь понять Promise? Что вы читали по теме? Например, читали этот раздел из популярного сейчас учебника? https://learn.javascript.ru/async

Comment: @Grundy эти промисы шли по дефолту как задание

Comment: @vsemozhebuty именно там читал, но так толком ничего и не понял. Не уверен, но может плохое понимание применения callback-ов не дает мне понять промисы?

Comment: Даже не знаю. Если читаете на английском, могу ещё посоветовать про асинхронность в JS: главы 24 и 25 отсюда: https://exploringjs.com/es6/index.html и весь раздел VIII  отсюда: https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/toc.html

Comment: @Torin_21, в текущем виде в коде, во-первых, синтаксические ошибки, во-вторых, ни один из приведенных промисов не разрешается, то есть нельзя дождаться окончания ни одного из них.

Answer (score 3):

Вы неправильно обрабатываете [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)-объект.
Для начала вот вам мат. часть [Promise on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Promise - это встроенный класс, соответственно при создании нового объекта через [оператор new](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new), вы должны вызвать один из callback-методов в контексте того `Promise` объекта, который создали. Два разных выражения `new Promise()` и `Promise.resolve()` порождают абсолютно разные контексты, иными словами это два разных объекта со своими внутренними обработчиками `resolve` и `reject`. Данные обработчики [инкапсулированы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) во внутренний механизм промиса. При вызове одного из этих обработчиков вы порождаете действие о завершении операции передав этим обработчикам данные в качестве аргументов `resolve(data)` или `reject(new Error('some error'))`. Метод `resolve` для успешной операции, а `reject` для ошибок.

Соответственно создав новый объект Promise, вы неправильно его обработали, и данный промис, созданный через оператор `new` никогда не выполнится, потому что он не обрабатывается должным образом.

```js
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => Promise.resolve('Cherkasy'), 1000);
});
```

Давайте проанализируем почему.

1. Вы создаете переменную `promise1` и сохраняете в ней инстанс на промис
2. В теле данного промиса вы вызываете `setTimeout` и после ожидания 1сек, вместо того чтобы вызвать `resolve` или `reject` созданного выше промиса вы создаете новый промис `Promise.resolve`.
3. Так как `setTimeout` не способен возвращать результаты кастомных методов, а созданный промис через оператор `new` никогда не обрабатывается, в переменной `promise1` сохраняется состояние промиса, которое никогда не завершится.

Вот так необходимо обрабатывать Promise с помощью setTimeout

```js
const resolvedPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('Cherkasy'), 1000);
});

const rejectedPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('Cherkasy not found')), 1200);
});
```

Но иногда бывает что не нужно прибегать к setTimeout и созданию нового объекта Promise, потому как результат нам уже известен и не нужно ожидать. Но для того чтобы соблюсти [контракт](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) данных используя Promise, разработчики придумали вот такое выражение:

```js
const resolvedPromise = Promise.resolve('Cherkasy');
const rejectedPromise = Promise.reject(new Error('Cherkasy not found'));
```

Весь вышеперечисленный код можно обрабатывать двумя способами и между этими способами существенная разница (Во первых это разное оформление, во вторых при использовании async/await, интерпретатор дойдя до оператора await, приостановит выполнение метода в контексте которого был вызван await, до тех пор пока Promise не вернет результат):

- [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
- [then](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)/[catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)

```js
// Обработка Promise с помощью async/await
async function() {
  try {
    const data1 = await resolvedPromise;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }

  try {
    const data2 = await rejectedPromise;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

// Обработка Promise с помощью then/catch
resolvedPromise
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.error(error))

  .then(() => rejectedPromise)
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.error(error))
;
```

Comment: _между этими способами существенная разница_ - какая разница?

Comment: Во первых очевидно что оформление блоков другое, во вторых при использовании async/await, интерпретатор, дойдя до оператора await приостановит выполнение метода в контексте которого был вызван await, до тех пор, пока Promise не вернет результат. При использовании then/catch - приостановки метода не произойдет, а данные сразу обрабатываются в колбеках, которые принимают в качестве аргументов then/catch.

Comment: Добавь это описание в ответ. Формулировка _данные сразу обрабатываются в колбеках_ - неверная. Они обрабатываются тогда, когда Promise вернет результат, и в этом поведение такое же как и с await

Comment: Ну и в примере надо было делать `resolvedPromise.then(data => console.log(data)).catch(error => console.error(error))
  .then(()=>rejectedPromise).then(data => console.log(data)).catch(error => console.error(error))` тогда можно было бы сравнивать поведение двух вариантов

Comment: Да, верно, я неправильно сформулировал. Спасибо, исправил.